# UrlActionResult in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionresult

I want to know is there any open source action result code available for asp.net mvc in which i can pass a URL and it will response out the content.

Just like there are some inbuilt Action results

- FileResult
- FileStreamResult

I want to build a custom Action Result in which i can pass a URL (basically an mp3 url) which will get downloaded in memory and the content will be streamed to the current executing response.

**It should also support resume download if supported by server and client. Thats a must for me.**

```
public UrlActionResult DownloadUrl(string url)
{
     return new UrlActionResult("http://www.example.com/audiofile.mp3");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a basic scenario you could use something like this:

```
public class DownloadResult : ActionResult
{
    private readonly FileStreamResult _fileStreamResult;

    public DownloadResult(string url, string contentType)
    {
        using (var myWebClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var myStream = myWebClient.OpenRead(url);
            _fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult(myStream, contentType);
        }
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        _fileStreamResult.ExecuteResult(context);
    }
}
```

However if you want to do the resume download it becomes a lot more complicated. [Here is a great article](http://tpeczek.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/range-requests-in-aspnet-mvc.html) with example code.

Comment: Yeah, that's a very good way indeed but i want to support resumable downloads. In the article you mentioned the code looks like working but now i am using custom classes made by myself in order to support this.

Comment: Yup that is the way you will have to go there is nothing in the asp.net-mvc framework that will support it out the box, you will have to write some code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to hide the url just use a redirect. Using a redirect with spare you server bandwidth:

```
public ActionResult DownloadUrl(string url)
{
     return new Redirect("http://www.example.com/audiofile.mp3");
}
```

Comment: I want to hide the url. :)